# Synapse XPath Extension in XSLT

Tags: xslt, wso2, apache-synapse

Is it possible to access Synapse XPATH extension from an XSLT. I want to use the get-property function in an XSLT, is it possible?

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:synapse="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    exclude-result-prefixes="synapse"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="synapse:get-property('paramName')" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think. XSLT is supported by 3rd party library.

Comment: The XSLT is used inside an XSLT mediator.